# non-invocable member PictureBox.ImageLocation cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working with the Windows Forms app. It connects to the **Flikr** website via free API key, searches images that I provide through the `textBox` and displays the names of the files that correspond to the keyword in the `imagesListBox`. When I click on the image name in the `imagesListBox` the image is displayed inside of the `pictureBox`. Now I am trying to save an image from the `pictureBox` and I get this error: "non-invocable member PictureBox.ImageLocation cannot be used like a method". Is there another method similar to `ImageLocation` which I can use to retrieve the image url address? Here is my code for the button which is supposed to save the image:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //method of saving image
            try
            {
                if (pictureBox.Image != null)
                {
                    //5
                    string filePath = PictureBox.ImageLocation();

                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

                    File.Copy(pictureBox.Text, Path.Combine(@"C:\", Path.GetFileName(pictureBox.Text)), true);

                    MessageBox.Show("The image has been saved to C drive.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return;
            }
        }
```

Searching and uploading images from Flikr:

```
private async void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // if flickrTask already running, prompt user 
            if (flickrTask?.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
            {
                var result = MessageBox.Show(
                   "Cancel the current Flickr search?",
                   "Are you sure?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                   MessageBoxIcon.Question);

                // determine whether user wants to cancel prior search
                if (result == DialogResult.No)
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    flickrClient.CancelPendingRequests(); // cancel search
                }
            }

            // Flickr's web service URL for searches                         
            var flickrURL = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=" +
               $"flickr.photos.search&api_key={KEY}&" +
               $"tags={inputTextBox.Text.Replace(" ", ",")}" +
               "&tag_mode=all&per_page=500&privacy_filter=1";

            imagesListBox.DataSource = null; // remove prior data source
            imagesListBox.Items.Clear(); // clear imagesListBox
            pictureBox.Image = null; // clear pictureBox
            imagesListBox.Items.Add("Loading..."); // display Loading...

            // invoke Flickr web service to search Flick with user's tags
            flickrTask = flickrClient.GetStringAsync(flickrURL);

            // await flickrTask then parse results with XDocument and LINQ
            XDocument flickrXML = XDocument.Parse(await flickrTask);

            // gather information on all photos
            var flickrPhotos =
               from photo in flickrXML.Descendants("photo")
               let id = photo.Attribute("id").Value
               let title = photo.Attribute("title").Value
               let secret = photo.Attribute("secret").Value
               let server = photo.Attribute("server").Value
               let farm = photo.Attribute("farm").Value
               select new FlickrResult
               {
                   Title = title,
                   URL = $"https://farm{farm}.staticflickr.com/" +
                     $"{server}/{id}_{secret}.jpg"
               };

            // clear imagesListBox
            imagesListBox.Items.Clear();

            // set ListBox properties only if results were found
            if (flickrPhotos.Any())
            {
                imagesListBox.DataSource = flickrPhotos.ToList();
                imagesListBox.DisplayMember = "Title";
            }
            else // no matches were found
            {
                imagesListBox.Items.Add("No matches");
            }
        }
```

Since it has been asked how I get images inside the pictureBox:

```
// display selected image
        private async void imagesListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(
           object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (imagesListBox.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                string selectedURL = ((FlickrResult)imagesListBox.SelectedItem).URL;

                // use HttpClient to get selected image's bytes asynchronously
                byte[] imageBytes = await flickrClient.GetByteArrayAsync(selectedURL);

                // display downloaded image in pictureBox                  
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
                {
                    pictureBox.Image = Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line to the following. **ImageLocation** is a property, not a method.

```
string filePath = pictureBox.ImageLocation;
```

Comment: "CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'PictureBox.ImageLocation'.

Comment: Oops, incorrect case. Should be using the variable "pictureBox" not the class "PictureBox", see my edited snippet.

Comment: Nice. It solved this problem but now I need to investigate why my file name is empty. I have a feeling it has something to do with pictureBox.Text